# Error while opening an excel file from c# win form using interop service and process.start()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, office-interop, system.diagnostics

I am using code for opening an excel sheet from temp folder.

I am using 2 options to open a file.
First I am using `process.start()`, if this is throwing an error, I will use the second one using `interop services`. But both  are throwing error on Win 8 pc with excel 2013 (365).

Please help 4 this.

The code is

```
try
{

   Process.Start("File Location");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  try
  {
    ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    theWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("File Location", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    ExcelApp.Visible = true;
    ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100;
    ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
    ExcelApp.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    theWorkbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    throw;
  }
  finally
  {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(theWorkbook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
  }

  throw;
}
finally
{

}
```

Comment: What error message/exception are you seeing? And at which line of code?

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this some days ago.

Try using this:

```
Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", "\" " + FileLocation+ " \"");
```

See that the "\" have white spaces in parameter.

Comment: `Process.Start("C:\temp\test.xlsx");` open a ***xlsx file*** if **Excel is installed**. If not installed, I don't know.